# Python itemgetter prints empty list instead of string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

distance_list = [('Brahmadatta Devadatta', 0.12844036697247707, '2, 6', '0, 10'),
                 ('Brahmadatta Devadatta', 0.07339449541284404, '2, 6', '1, 9'),
                 ('Brahmadatta Sujata', 0.11009174311926606, '2, 6', '4, 8')]

for key, value in groupby(sorted(distance_list), key=itemgetter(0)):
    print map(itemgetter(1), value) #works for printing float numbers
    print map(itemgetter(2), value) # returns an empty list
```

Why does itemgetter return empty list instead of returning the corresponding string

**Expected Output:**

```
2, 6
2, 6
2, 6
```

**Generated Output:**

```
[ ]  
[ ]  
[ ]
```

Comment: I get this, `['2, 6', '2, 6']
['2, 6']
`

Comment: Are you sure - I concur with @enginefree

Comment: @enginefree Works only if I comment out the previous line.

Comment: Did you happen to have *both* maps on?  `value` isn't a list but a grouper object, and so you can only iterate through it once.  Add `value = list(value)` if you want multiple iterations to work.

Comment: Because if you keep the previous line in, it exhausts the iterator

Comment: @DSM, you should put that as an answer.

Comment: Your OP was a bit misleading as it had the first line commented out... ;) But it makes sense - do as @DSM suggests and you'll be fine

Comment: Default list/tuple sort behavior is to use the first element of a list, you don't need to use `itemgetter` for the first sort in this example.

Comment: @monkut not true - it will use all elements of the sequence/iterable... no need to include all of them for sort in this case - probably harmless, but if it had 1000 items of complex objects, then errr, def. not a good idea

Comment: Thats a good point!  thanks for mentioning it!